# How add TreeListNodes to TreeListNode?

Tags: c#, devexpress, treelist

I want delete nodes and insert it again. This code delete nodes, but does not add. Is it possible to add `TreeListNodes (newNodes)` to `TreeListNode (myNode)` ?
What i doing wrong?

```
TreeListNode myNode = treeList1.FindNode((node) => {
    return node["ColumnName"].ToString() == "test";
});

var child = myNode.Nodes;

TreeListNodes newNodes = new TreeListNodes(treeList1);

for (int i = child.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    newNodes.Add(child[i]);
    treeList1.DeleteNode((DevExpress.XtraTreeList.Nodes.TreeListNode) child[i]);
}

myNode.Nodes.Add(newNodes);
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, you're trying **to reorder children** of the specific node in reverse order. 
If so, adding/removing nodes is not necessary an I suggest you to use the following approach([MoveNode](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraTreeListTreeList_MoveNodetopic(pDAWbw))):

```
TreeListNode testNode = treeList1.FindNode(
    node => object.Equals(node["Name"], "test"));
TreeListNodes children = testNode.Nodes;
for(int i = children.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    treeList1.MoveNode(children[i], testNode, false, position: 0);
```

Alternative way([SetNodeIndex](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraTreeListTreeList_SetNodeIndextopic)):

```
TreeListNodes children = testNode.Nodes;
for(int i = children.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    treeList1.SetNodeIndex(children[i], 0);
```

p.s. I have tested the approaches above with the [latest(v17.1) version](https://www.devexpress.com/Subscriptions/New-2017-1.xml) which announced multiple improvements in TreeList API.

Comment: Dmitry, thx for reply. Yes, i want reorder nodes. But I can't know in advance order of items. Therefor, i want get nodes, order this and insert again.

Comment: Дмитрий, все правильно, однако я заранее не знаю порядок нод. Поэтому я хочу собрать их, отсортировать их, и пихнуть обратно

Comment: @АхихТиманов: If so, I believe, it is possible to calculate the resulting node indices depending on specific sorting condition. Adding/removing of multiple nodes instead of moving can be worst approach from the performance point of view.

Comment: IMHO, DX guys should do some improvements in this area(nodes reordering). I suggest you contact it directly and describe the specific use-cases. From my personal practice, they can make some decisions for useful scenarios quite fast (in upcoming minor updates).